# Icon does not show up on the action bar - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I'm trying to show a camera icon on the action bar, but it does not work. The menu shows up and works fine but the camera icon does not show up. Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

The menu code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_camera"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
    android:title="@string/action_camera"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:title="@string/action_delete"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.cfb.daily_selfie" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DailySelfieActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayPictureActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_picture"
        android:parentActivityName=".DailySelfieActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.cfb.daily_selfie.DailySelfieActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmNotificationReceiver" >
    </receiver>

 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Bellow onCreate()

```
public class DailySelfieActivity extends ListActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE =    "br.com.cfb.daily_selfie.MESSAGE";
private static final String TAG = "DS-DailySelfieActivity";
private final static int INTENT_ID = 322;

private SelfieViewAdapter mAdapter;
private SelfieRecord mSelfieRecord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView selfieListView = getListView();
    final View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);
    selfieListView.addFooterView(footerView);
    mAdapter = new SelfieViewAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
    loadListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    //      Create Alarm to take a selfie
    Alarm mAlarm = new Alarm(getApplicationContext());

    //      Enable filtering when the user types in the virtual keyboard
    //      selfieListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   //      Set an setOnItemClickListener on the ListView
    selfieListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

   //              Display a Toast message indicting the selected item
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position = " +position + " id = " +id
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mSelfieRecord = (SelfieRecord) mAdapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date = " +mSelfieRecord.getDate()
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //              Display Picture
            Intent intent = new Intent(DailySelfieActivity.this, DisplayPictureActivity.class);
            Bitmap mPicture = mSelfieRecord.getPicture();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, mPicture);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Bellow OnCreateOptionsMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_daily_selfie, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please post your activity.

Comment: It's your icon in your drawable folder?

Comment: Did you add the name of the menu file to  `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_file_name, menu)` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: post your activity code please

Comment: @M_Y. Yes, I did. I added the OnCreateOptionsMenu. The menu works fine, just the icon desn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

What about `ic_menu_camera`? Although I do see references to `ic_action_camera` elsewhere, that is not coming up for me. I do have access to `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"` though (note the addition of the `@android:drawable`)

Or, as @acostela indicated, make sure it's in your drawable folder to use just the
`android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"`.

Comment: @Xarep, The ic_action_camera it is in the drawable directory. I also chenged to android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" and run the applictaion and the icon still doesnt show up. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Folks, My original Activity was extending an ListView, so I changed and extended the ActionBar and it worked well.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why extending the ListActivity would have caused that problem, but glad you got it working @Carlos

Answer (score 0):

my original Activity was extending a ListView, so I changed and extended the ActionBar and it worked well.

Thank you,
Carlos